# How does x86 handle byte vs word addressing when executing instructions and reading/writing data?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, instruction-encoding

So I am learning how x86 works and have come across people saying that it is byte-addressable, yet can read words, double words, etc.
How does the processor decide which method to use and when?
E.g. for accessing the next instruction and when a user wants to read/write to memory, which addressing mode is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every memory access has an operand-size specified by the machine-code instruction.**  (Addressing mode isn't the right term: different addressing modes are different ways of specifying the lowest address of the chunk of memory to be accessed, like `[rdi]` vs. `[rdi + rdx*8]` vs. `[RIP + rel32]`)

**Encoding  different operand-sizes is done with prefixes (for 16 vs. 32 vs. 64-bit for integer instructions) or a different opcode for the same mnemonic (8-bit integer).**  Or with bits in the VEX or EVEX prefix for AVX / AVX512 instructions that can use xmm, ymm, or zmm registers.

Decoding also depends on the current mode implying the default operand-size: 32 for 32 and 64-bit mode, or 16 for 16-bit mode.  A `66` opererand-size prefix implies the opposite size.

In 64-bit mode, the `.W` (width) bit in the REX prefix sets the operand-size to 64-bit.  (And some instructions like `push`/`pop` default to 64-bit operand-size with no prefix needed, but most instructions like `add`/`sub`/`mov` still default to 32-bit)

There's also a `0x67` address-size prefix which swaps addressing modes to the other size.  (16 vs. 32 or in 64-bit mode 64 -> 32.)

---

For example, `mov [rdi], eax` is a dword store, and the machine-code encoding will specify that by using no special prefixes on the opcode for 16/32/64-bit operand-size.  (see https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov for the available encodings.  But note that Intel's manual *doesn't* mention `66` operand-size prefixes in each entry: it has 2 identical encodings with different sizes.  You have to know which one needs a `66` prefix based on the current mode's default.)

16-bit operand-size like `mov [rdi], ax` will have the same machine code by with a `66` operand-size prefix.

8-bit operand-size (`mov [rdi], al`) has its own opcode, no prefixes needed.

`movzx` / [`movsx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) are interesting cases: the memory access size is different from the destination register.  The memory-access size (byte or word) is specified by the opcode.  Operand-size prefixes only affect the destination size.  Except x86-64 `63 /r`  `movsxd` (dword->qword sign-extension) where a `66` operand-size prefix *does* shrink the memory-access size down to `m16` to match the destination.

Similarly for SIMD instructions; the instruction encoding uniquely determines the memory-access size, along with the registers read or written.

Comment: Can we demonstrate by means of a simple example? If I say MOV AL, [0110], can I safely say it is a "word instruction" because the operand, 0110, is two bytes large?

Comment: @DeanP: For that instruction, the *address-size* is "word", assuming you're in 16-bit mode so a bare `0110` is interpreted as a 16-bit (hex?) number.  The *operand-size* is "byte", because `mov` is transferring 1 byte from memory to a byte register, AL.