# Casting a reference to a pointer to a reference to a void*

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the following well defined behavior?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void reallocate_something(void *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    void *dest = malloc(size);
    memcpy(dest, source_and_result, size);
    free(source_and_result);
    source_and_result = dest;
}

void reallocate_something(int *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    // I the cast safe in this use case?
    reallocate_something(reinterpret_cast<void*&>(source_and_result), size);
}

int main() {
    const size_t size = 4 * sizeof(int);
    int *start = static_cast<int*>(malloc(size));
    *start = 0;

    std::cout << start << ' ' << *start << '\n';
    reallocate_something(start, size);
    std::cout << start << ' ' << *start << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The code uses a `reinterpret_cast` to pass a reference to a pointer and re-allocate it, free it, and set it to the new area allocated. Is this well defined?

In particular A `static_cast` would work if I did not want to pass a reference, and that would be well defined.

The tag is C++, and I'm asking about this code as-is within the C++ standard.

Comment: This is not well defined for `void*` and `int*` are not similar. Refer to **Type aliasing** section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

Comment: @Lingxi Isn't that to simplified? `malloc` always takes and returns `void*`, and yet we allocate any pointer with that (and thus have to cast).

Comment: Why not `std::realloc`?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Because I'm checking an issue of understanding the standard  and undefined behavior, not best practices. You might as well say why not use `std::array` for this example.

Comment: is `&` in `reinterpret_cast<void*&>(source_and_result)` necessary in this function call `reallocate_something(reinterpret_cast<void*&>(source_and_result), size);`?

Comment: @Harry The functions takes an original pointer, copies at somewhere else, frees the original pointer and changes the original pointer passed (thus why I want a reference in this example). I thought I could use a static cast somehow, or perhaps forwarding , but none of that worked. If this is undefined I'll use a `**` and pass the address of the original pointer rather than a reference (in the inner call to the `void*` taking function. If I did not need a reference a normal static cast would work, but I'd have to return the new pointer (different design).

Comment: @kabanus You missed the point. Anyway, I posted an answer.

Comment: The first occurrence of `*start` causes undefined behaviour by reading uninitialized memory

Comment: @M.M I don't think that's true in the strict sense. UB (in the language lawyer sense) does not mean unpredictable in a general sense. I think it's guaranteed by the standard that whatever was sitting in the allocated memory would be printed, whatever that is. As long as `malloc` was called (or whatever storage allocation you used), I think it's not UB. Anyway, the second print is the same.

Comment: @kabanus there is no guarantee in the standard of "whatever is sitting in the allocated memory" -- the behaviour of reading such memory is undefined "in the language lawyer sense" (which is the only sense of UB since the standard defines the meaning of the term)

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I thought it was merely unspecified in this case. I corrected the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the following well defined behavior?

No, it's not. You can't interpret `int *` pointer with `void *` handle, `int` and `void` are not similar types. You can *convert* an `int *` pointer to `void *` and back. If your function takes a reference, to do the conversion you need a new temporary variable of type `void *` to hold the result of the conversion, and then you have to assign it back, like in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69641609/9072753 .

Anyway, just make it a template, and write nice C++ code with placement new. Something along:

```
template<typename T>
void reallocate_something(T *&pnt, size_t cnt) {
    T *dest = reinterpret_cast<T *>(malloc(cnt * sizeof(T)));
    if (dest == NULL) throw ...;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
       new (dest[i]) T(pnt[i]);
    }
    free(static_cast<void*>(pnt));
    pnt = dest;
}
```

Comment: doesn't this example assume that pointers can be strictly aligned back to back?

Comment: I do not understand what "strictly aligned" and "aligned back to back" means. `malloc` returns a pointer properly aligned for any object.

Comment: @KamiCuk  :-)   
malloc made a contiguous run of ram. Which is then accessed as an array. 
But if the size of the object in the array is less than the machine’s alignment, won’t it need more than simply sizeof(obj)  x num ? 
I’ve only worked on Intel platform, so never had to worry with it myself.

Comment: `if the size of the object in the array is less than the machine’s alignment`  For all standard types and objects that have to be false. If you make a custom type with compiler extensions, that's on you that you can't use malloc. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-object-types-t

Comment: Thanks a lot @KamiCuk.
I did a lot of playing in Visual Studio with arrays, structs, sizeof(), alignof() on 64bit compile . . .
I still have to be curious what happens on hardware that will cause exceptions if you access unaligned memory.
So byte a[10];  on a 4 or 8-byte hardware:
Is a[1] one byte after a[0] ?
If it is, wouldn't you get an exception accessing a[2], a[2], etc
If not, that seems like sizeof(byte) on that hardware would be the hardware alignment.....   so sizeof(byte [10]) would be 40  on a 4-byte aligned machine....  instead of 10?

Comment: `what happens on hardware that will cause exceptions if you access unaligned memory` It depends on the specific hardware and specific instruction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491578/whats-the-actual-effect-of-successful-unaligned-accesses-on-x86 `So byte a[10]; on a 4 or 8-byte hardware` I do not understand the example, a byte is a byte, 4 bytes is a word. The compiler generates code so that bytes are accessed with instructions for bytes, so all is aligned properly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58628157/9072753

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm not sure but I feel this is the correct way to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void reallocate_something(void *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    void *dest = malloc(size);
    memcpy(dest, source_and_result, size);
    free(source_and_result);
    source_and_result = dest;
}

void reallocate_something(int *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    // Is the cast safe in this use case?
    void *temp = static_cast<void*>(source_and_result);
    reallocate_something(temp, size);
    source_and_result = static_cast<int*>(temp);
}

int main() {
    const size_t size = 4 * sizeof(int);
    int *start = static_cast<int*>(malloc(size));

    std::cout << start << ' ' << *start << '\n';
    reallocate_something(start, size);
    std::cout << start << ' ' << *start << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not bad. Note you can use a `static_cast` which is safer, and shows the value of your answer. The reason I prefer it "inside" (the re-assignment) is that I will have multiple overloads though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not well defined for `void*` and `int*` are *not similar*. Refer to **Type aliasing** section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

Note that pointer round trip via `void*` like below is well defined. Particularly, there is no *type aliasing* here.

```
T* pt = ...;

void* p = pt;

auto pt2 = static_cast<T*>(p);
assert(pt2 == pt);
```

This is different from following code with *type aliasing* which is not well defined.

```
T* pt = ...;

void* p = nullptr;
reinterpret_cast<T*&>(p) = pt; // or *reinterpret_cast<T**>(&p) = pt;

auto pt2 = static_cast<T*>(p);
assert(pt2 == pt);
```

It follows that your sample code can be revised as below.

```
void reallocate_something(int *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    void* p = source_and_result;
    reallocate_something(p, size);
    source_and_result = static_cast<int*>(p);
}
```

Or better yet

```
void* reallocate_something(void *source_and_result, size_t size) {
    void *dest = malloc(size);
    memcpy(dest, source_and_result, size);
    free(source_and_result);
    return dest;
}

void reallocate_something(int *&source_and_result, size_t size) {
    source_and_result = static_cast<int*>(reallocate_something(source_and_result, size));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I this is what Harry had as well. I wanted the assignment "inside" on purpose in my example, but this is a valid solution.

Comment: @kabanus Added another one which I think is better. BTW, what's your original goal/purpose/motivation?

Comment: Yea, that solution was also something I was considering once I was sure the type alias was undefined. The real purpose is refactoring a lot of Cuda gpu allocations, and re-purposing the original pointers to point to these. "malloc" was an alias for the Cuda operations. With the solutions here the whole data transfer API and preparing the data structures becomes considerably shorter and nicer (easier to read).

Answer (score 0):

There exist platforms where the bitwise representations of `int*` and `void*` are incompatible.  On such platforms, it would be often be impossible for a compiler to allow a reference of one type to meaningfully act upon an object of the other, and the Standard thus refrains from requiring that implementations do so.

Of course, the vast majority of platforms use the same representation for all PODS pointer types, and when the Standard was written it was obvious to pretty much everyone that (1) it allowed compilers for such platforms to process reference type casts usefully, and (2) compilers should process such casts usefully except when there was a compelling reason to do otherwise.  It was expected that the only compiler writers who would care about whether such conversions had defined behavior would be those targeting platforms where such support would be expensive (e.g. requiring that any `int*` whose address is taken be stored using the same bit pattern as `void*`, even if that would require shuffling its bits around when using it to fetch an `int`), and compiler writers were expected know more about the costs and benefits of such support than the Committee ever could.

Most implementations can be configured to process such casts in the manner that would have been expected when the Standard was written, but the Standard does not mandate such support; when such configurations, the behavior of the construct should be regarded as defined by a popular language extension.

Comment: There exist platform where int* and void* are incompatible? Uhmm. Machine knows nothing about int nor void.

Comment: @user13947194: There exist platforms where hardware addresses identify units of storage which are larger than 8 bits, but which have instructions to access (e.g.) the upper or lower half of a storage location.  Some even have an instruction which accepts a pointer and index, shifts the index right one bit and adds it to the pointer, and then accesses the top or bottom half of the word at the resulting address (chosen via the bottom bit of the index).  On such machines, a `char*` may combine a hardware address and an index, while an `int*` would merely contain the hardware address.

Comment: @user13947194: A compiler for such a machine could process code in such a way that the "index" part of every `char*` is always zero or one, and an `int*` would reserve space for an index part which would always be written as zero and ignored when a pointer was used, and doing so would make the representations of `char*` and `int*` compatible, but most tasks could be accomplished more efficiently if `int*` omitted the index word, and the index of a `char*` was allowed to be greater than 1.

Comment: Alright; since int* and char* need different access on those machines; how come void* can be used as a common bridge?

Comment: @user13947194: The type `void*` is specified by the Standard to use the same representation as `char*`.  A compiler may convert a `char*` or `void*` to an aligned address to an `int*` by shifting the offset part right one place, adding the base address, and using the resulting address.  Conversion from `int*` to `void*` would involve copying the base address and applying an offset of zero.

Comment: @user13947194: An implementation may decide to always normalize `char*` values that are stored in memory so that the offset is 0 or 1 (or in the range 0 to 3, depending upon the word size), and if it stores things that way conversion to `int*` could simply ignore and omit the offset part.  That would make `void*` to `int*` conversions more efficient, but would likely make `char*` operations less efficient.

Comment: Firstly you have to provide me where in the standard specifies that void* and char* shall use the same representation. Anyhow, you have said alot, and still have showed why void** and int** are incompatible. Your opening arguments was that on some machines, int* and char* need be handled differently. That's ok; And if you use a plain int* to void* you will still suffer performance penalty. Same as if you did int** to void**. So as you can see, I dont understand what you are telling me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427587/void-a-generic-pointer If you check what @IdeaHat said. I think that is the real rational. Being that dereferencing a void* is illegal, but you could have an array of void* aka void**. In that case void** is derencable and indexable. Then void**[1] != int**[1].

Comment: *Firstly you have to provide me where in the standard specifies that void\* and char\* shall use the same representation.*  N1570 6.2.5 [Types], paragraph 28: " A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."  On a machine such as described earlier, given `int *p, **q; void **v;` an assignment `*q=p;` would simply write the hardware-address part of `p` to `*q`, but `*v = p`; would both copy the hardware-address part of `p` and write a zero offset.

Comment: And what would int i; void *p;  p = &i; do? By the wauy, thubs up for clarrifying the standard.

Comment: @user13947194: On the indicated platform, that would store the hardware address of `i` into the hardware-address portion of `p`, and set the offset portion to zero.  If one were to later do `int *ip = p;`, that would either take the hardware-address portion and add half of the offset portion (which would be zero) and store that into `ip`, or else just copy the hardware-address portion of `p` into `ip` and ignore the offset portion.